# Remind me when I haven't done X for 10 days (and button to click whenever I do X)

Tags: gratis, productivity

I must do a particular activity at least every 10 days. I sometimes do it more often, and sometimes I am busy and the task slips away.

Recurring reminder/task is not a good option: Let's say I should do X on March 10, then...

- If I actually do it on March 8, then the next time must be March 18.
- If I actually do it on March 12, then the next time must be March 22.

---

Is there a Chrome extension that does this?

- It should have a button (or some other mechanism) that I can click when I do X, so that it can calculate when to remind me.
- It should show a non-intrusive reminder, such as the extension color becoming red, as I am likely to ignore it for a few days.

Bonus if I can handle several tasks in parallel, for instance do X at least every 10 days and do Y at least every 25 days.

If there is no Chrome extension, a Mac top bar widget is OK, or even an Android app.
Gratis, ideally open source.

Answer (score 0):

I propose using something more mobile and flexible than Chrome extensions, something that will be accessible to you whenever you go. For example, Telegram app.

Here we have two options:

1. Built-in reminders in Telegram

[image]

Here you simply add the message to Saved messages and by long tap on it set the reminder time.

**Cons**:

- lack of auto-calculation of the interval
- lack of recurrence with a predefined interval, you should re-schedule the reminder manually.

2. Reminder bot, for example [@yastabot](https://tg://resolve?domain=yastabot) ([description](https://telegramic.org/bot/yastabot/)).

It has built-in the functionality to create reminders in a free verbal form

```
/remindme in 30 minutes to leave for work
/remindme at 4pm to pick up the kids from school
/remindme every 2 saturdays to fill up gas
```

It will fire a reminder like TG message, you can reschedule it for any interval: day, week, 10 days.

[image]

**Cons**: it also not fully automatic in recurrence, 'cause doesn't allow reccure with preset interval, but at least it allows easy re-scheduling with setting arbitrary interval after popping up.

**Pros**: it has different timezones support, Google Calendar integration and finally

> Bonus if I can handle several tasks in parallel, for instance do X at least every 10 days and do Y at least every 25 days.

it allows unlimited tasks in parallel like you describe here

Maybe you will find better Telegram reminder bots with more extended functionality, there are many of them.